# Triggering unit test on solution build (VS 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, testing, configuration

I am new to testing so please bear with the obvious unfamiliarity.

I have a solution with multiple projects, configurations and app settings. There is already a compiler directive to warn on non-Release builds but this is often ignored. I'm looking for a more visible warning during testing. Something that acts as a checklist for testers to do before they can proceed.

I have a unit test project in the solution. There are three questions here:

- Can a unit test be set up to run as a post-build event?
- Is there a way to prevent publishing the solution in non-Release mode?
- Is using a unit test trigger standard practice?

If there are other alternatives, what are they?

Comment: Do you use MStest or NUnit?

Comment: MSTest I guess. Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.

Comment: Running as postbuild: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865593/running-unit-tests-after-local-build-with-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Continuous testing VS2010: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c074d3c6-71e2-4628-9e7c-7690e706aef4

Comment: Have you thought about using a continuous integration server?